# Coordinates of derivatives in the standard polynomial basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^5-5x^4$.
>
> Find coordinates of $f',\ f''$ and $f'''$ in the basis $\{1,\ x,\ x^2,\ x^3,\ x^4,\ x^5\}$

What I have so far is to take the derivative say $f'(x)=5x^4-20x^3$ and then the coordinate vector would be $(0,0,0,-20,5,0)$.

Am I on the right path or completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.